# How can i align the labels with bars in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to align labels with bars in `ggplot2`?
Here is the code that I am using. Any help will be appreciated

```
     library(ggplot2)       
     output <- CLD(TKM.means$emmeans, details=T, Letters=letters)
     p <- ggplot(data=output$emmeans, aes(x=genotypes))
     p <- p + geom_bar(aes(reorder(genotypes, emmean ) , y=emmean), stat="identity", width=0.8)
     p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emmean-SE, ymax=emmean+SE), width=0.4)
     p <- p + geom_text(aes(y=emmean+0.3, label=.group))
     p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1 , vjust = 0.3))
     p <- p + labs(title="Main", x="Geno", y="Yield")
     p
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. This could be an `hjust` issue or perhaps you have spaces before those letters.

Answer (score 0):

The text in `.group` contains spaces. If you strip those spaces, they will align the way you want.